# Is there a way to not save sent mail in the Gmail Mail Send API?

Tags: google-apps-script, microsoft-graph-api, gmail-api, google-developers-console

Goal- Send mail using the GMAIL API and not have the emails sent saved in the "sent mail" folder.

I have worked with the Microsoft Graph API for sending mail where you can create a JSON setting "saveToSentITems": "false" but I wanted to find out if the same exists for GMAIL.

I have looked extensively through the Gmail Mail API documentation, but haven't found anything related to saving the emails to the sent folder. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: I doubt that there is such a method.  But you can delete them all with a time based trigger and the Gmail API

Comment: That's a good point, I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Gmail filter](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579) that automatically puts those sent messages in the Trash.